# Spring boot RabbitMq health check reports UP even when network connection is down

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-rabbit

Here is the scenario I'm testing. I require a vpn connection to reach the RabbitMQ server. When I start my spring boot based application with the vpn up, all is good: the application starts up fine and the rabbitMQ health check report UP with the proper version to rabbitMQ server.

When I disconnect the vpn, the RabbitMQ health check continues to repost UP even though the RabbitMQ server isn't reachable anymore.

At the end, what I want is some retry capabilities (Backoff) for normal rabbitMQ operations but not for the health check. Health checks should always fail fast while the application tries to recover from a lost network connection. But even the simplest scenario (without any retries) the health check doesn't hang (yeah!) but doesn't report any failures

I even followed this with no luck: [SpringBoot Disable rabbitTemplate retry policy for rabbit health check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362393/springboot-disable-rabbittemplate-retry-policy-for-rabbit-health-check)

I would appreciate any help/pointers.

**Environment:**

- java 8 (1.8.0_162)
- Spring boot 1.5.4
- spring-amqp & spring-rabbit 1.7.3
- Rabbit MQ server: 3.7.5
- No special rabbitmq configuration aside from host, port, username and password.